# Acceder a un dato en una Estructura de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, diccionarios

Soy muy novato en Python, pero con experiencia en otros lenguajes.
Mi problema surge al intentar utilizar un módulo para leer archivos DBF; y que aún no asimilo las estructuras de datos de Python.
El ejemplo de uso que trae este módulo es:

```py
from dbfread import DBF
for record in DBF('people.dbf'):
    print(record)
```

Dando como resultado...

```
OrderedDict([('NAME', 'Alice'), ('BIRTHDATE', datetime.date(1987, 3, 1))])
OrderedDict([('NAME', 'Bob'), ('BIRTHDATE', datetime.date(1980, 11, 12))])
```

Donde NAME y BIRTHDATE, son los nombres de campos de 'people.dbf'.
'Alice' y datetime.date(1987, 3, 1) son los valores de dichos campos, en el primer registro.
Mi problema es que no se como referenciar esos valores para que, en cada iteración, los asigne a variables.
O sea, algo así como...

```py
nombre = record.OrderedDict('NAME')     # que a la variable nombre le asigne 'Alice'
fecha = record.OrderedDict('BIRTHDATE') # que a la variable fecha le asigne datetime.date(1987, 3, 1)
```

El módulo carga un único registro por cada iteración. O sea, no carga todos los registros en una estructura que luego pueda recorrerse.
En cada iteración está disponible solamente el último registro leído.

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) **es una subclase de [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict)** (diccionarios) que a diferencia de éstos mantiene el orden de inserción de las parejas clave-valor además de implementar algunos métodos propios.

Tradicionalmente los diccionarios al igual que los conjuntos (tablas hash) no mantenían el orden de inserción de sus items, eran colecciones intrínsecamente desordenadas por lo que cada vez que se iteraba sobre ellos podían retornar los items en un orden diferente. Digo tradicionalmete, porque en Python 3.6 se llevó a cabo una reimplementación y optimización de los diccionarios que como efecto colateral mantenian el orden de inserción como hace `OrderedDict`. A partir de Python 3.7 esto ya no es un efecto colateral de la implementación, sino que es una característica de los diccionarios oficialmente, por lo que `OrderedDict` a perdido bastante utilidad.

Por lo tanto, para acceder a un  valor  determinado simplemente se indiza igual que en un diccionario normal, mediante la clave:

> ```
> >>> diccionario = {"Nombre": "Alicia", "Edad": 29}
> >>> diccionario["Nombre"]
> 'Alicia'
>
> >>> from collections import OrderedDict
> >>> ord_dicc = OrderedDict((("Nombre", "Alicia"), ("Edad", 29))) 
> >>> ord_dicc["Nombre"]
> 'Alicia'
> ```

En tu caso concreto:

```
for record in DBF('people.dbf'):
    nombre = record['NAME']
    fecha = record['BIRTHDATE']
```

Dado que mantienen el orden, también podrías hacer:

```
for record in DBF('people.dbf'):
    nombre, fecha = record.values()
```

Si te interesa construir algún contenedor con todos los registros, por ejemplo una lista de listas, puedes hacer algo así:

```
records = [list(record.values()) for record in DBF('people.dbf')]
print(records)
```

> ```
> [['Alice', datetime.date(1987, 3, 1)], ['Bob', datetime.date(1980, 11, 12)]]
> ```

Comment: Ya lo probé y funcionó!!! No solo en el ejemplo, sino también (obviamente) en el problema real.
Agradezco tu amabilidad!!!